# UWP - built-in crop tool

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I want to select an image from phone gallery, and then open this image in windows phone 10 built-in crop tool. I'm opening the file with `FileOpenPicker` and file is opened, but I don't know how to pass the file to the crop tool, I even don't know what is the name of crop tool, or how to open it and pass a parameter. I have searched the Internet but I found nothing. Could you provide me any clue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows Phone 8 you could do this with [`PhotoChooserTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394019%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). I don't know of a built-in way to do that in an UWP app. I've stumbled across [a custom control by Diederik Krols](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/08/14/An-ImageCropper-control-for-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx) which seems to do the job, but I don't have any first hand experience with it.

Comment: The class doesn't exist in UWP. I don't know what else should i try

Comment: You could give a try the [custom `ImageCropper` control](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/08/14/An-ImageCropper-control-for-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx) I linked to above.